# invoke fragment from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

by pressing a button inside the main fragment, I wanna call the second fragment in that place

```
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
    Fragment frag = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:
            frag = new LoginFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_offline:
            frag = new OfflineFragment();
            break;
    }

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    FragmentManager manager = 
    mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never create an `Activity` instance . Its a Component and managed by system itself(Intent). Use `getActivity()` to get the `Context` of `Activity`.

```
 FragmentManager manager =
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, frag);
    transaction.commit();
```

You should take a look at [Android Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with getChildFragmentManager(); of the fragment to get the fragment manager to perform all your fragment related operations instead of getting it from using the fragmentManager from the getActivity() method. It help you a lot on reloading the fragment on resume of it again at later point of time.